# How to delete a specific character automatically from a text file using Python?

Tags: python, string, replace, char, text-files

I am trying to use a bit of code for a project to take combinations of a set of alphanumeric characters and write them into a .txt file. When I open the file from my device, it shows the following:

```
[aaaa
[aaab
[aaac
...
]fh52
...
```

The code should just be outputting the letters and numbers, no other characters and yet it still is. I can deal with the .txt file having these "artifacts" but I need a way of deleting these artifacts using Python in the future.

**What I would think the code should look like:**

```
unwanted_chars="[]"
datafile=open("Combinations.txt", 'a+')
for line in datafile:
    for char in line:
        if char in unwanted_chars:
            line.replace(char,"")
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You never changed the file.  All  you changed was the copy of the line in memory -- you have to write the data back to the file after you've made the change.  Please work through a tutorial on file read & write to see how these things work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close.  First, you don't need that `if` statement.  Second, the `replace` method for `str` doesn't alter the item in place, so your last line isn't doing anything.  You'd need to read the file in, replace the characters, and then write it back out.

```
with open('Combinations.text') as f:
    lines=list(f)
for k, line in enumerate(lines):
    for c in unwanted_chars:
        line=line.replace(c,'')
    lines[k]=line

with open('Combinations.text','w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(lines))
```